# invalid literal for int() with base 10: "john"

Tags: python, django

this is my `views.py`:

```
def get_contacts(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)
    contact_list = []

    name=None

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        name=request.user.username

    contact_list = contact.objects.filter(user=name).values_list('friend',flat=True)

    friend_list=simplejson.dumps(list(contact_list))

    return HttpResponse(friend_list,mimetype="application/json")
```

and this is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):

        return unicode(self.user.username)
```

and here is my error , when i'm trying to call `get_contact_list`

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'John'
```

Comment: Well what would you expect `int('John')` to give you, exactly?

Comment: but where I call int('John')? I don't understand what is int(), where is it come from?

Comment: We need to see the entire stack trace.

Comment: I'm calling get_contacts() from javascript,

Comment: We don't have enough information to answer.

Comment: sorry 
I copy my models.py partially , here is my contact db 

class contact(models.Model) :
 user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
 friend = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,related_name='friend_name')
 
 def __unicode__(self):
  return unicode(self.friend)

Comment: btw, what is `get_contact_list` ? I see only `get_contacts`

Comment: what exactly you want to know, It works before, but when I change my contact db, before it was without foreignkeys, just 2 charfields, it was ok, but now when I put foreigKey I'm getting this error

Comment: get_contact_list is type, I mean get_contacts

Comment: The problem is in code you haven't shown us.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve carefully and follow the instructions.  You might find that going through this process reveals the problem to you, even.

Comment: So did you update your schema after changing the model field? Post the schema of your table.

Comment: yes and problem is from db , I again take my previous db and it works. How can ForeignKey field generate this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter user column using a name. Instead of

```
contact.objects.filter(user=name)...
```

try

```
contact.objects.filter(user__username=name)...
```

Comment: this was my contact db 
 
class contact(models.Model) :

 user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 friend = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 
 def __unicode__(self):
  return self.friend

now I changed and make my fields as ForeignKeys like this 

class contact(models.Model) :

 user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,related_name='nm1')
 friend = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,related_name='nm2')
 
 def __unicode__(self):
  return self.friend



And after this changes , when I try to use my python function

Comment: So did you try my suggestion?

Comment: in my contact user field is just an charfield , so it has not username attribute or field ,